# User level usage reporting on Office365

Tags: office-365, site-usage

We have a company intranet hosted on Office365 running SharePoint 2013. Everyone logs into this using domain credentials via ADFS. I know in SharePoint server there's usage reporting which shows user level reports on individual sites. Is this possible on Office365?

Answer (score 1):

To view a usage report or a search report

- Sign in to the Office 365 Admin Center as a search administrator.
- Choose Admin > SharePoint. You’re now in the SharePoint admin center.
- Choose search.
- Choose View Usage Reports.
- Click a link on the page to retrieve a report. The report opens in an
  Excel spreadsheet or in another program that you can find online.

[Link to source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/view-usage-and-search-reports-HA103640042.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Andrey but that doesn't show us the user level information we're after. Is it possible to enable it?